# What is the difference between a workspace and repository in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm starting to familiarize myself with Bazel.  But even at the beginning of the Getting Started page I am running into a conceptual difficulty.

On the [first Getting Started page](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref) a **`Workspace`** is defined as a directory tree with a `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` file in the top-level directory.  When defining **`Repository`**, this same directory is called the `root` of the repository.  To me, this sounds like two names for the same thing.  Is there a difference between these terms that just isn't being made clear on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have exactly one [workspace](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref#workspace) in use. It's the first folder containing a `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` file found by traversing the (recursive) parents of the directory where you run the `bazel` command. It includes all of the files in that folder (recursively), except in folders containing their own `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel`, or a few other exceptions.

A [repository](https://bazel.build/concepts/build-ref#repositories) is *any* folder containing a `WORKSPACE` or `WORKSPACE.bazel` file. The workspace is the "main repository", the rest are "external repositories". The `WORKSPACE` files for external repositories are only checked for their name, they are not used for anything else.

The current workspace's `WORKSPACE` file specifies which [external repositories](https://bazel.build/external/overview) to load via [workspace rules](https://bazel.build/reference/be/workspace). Some of these rules use a `WORKSPACE` file from the external repository, others will create a minimal `WORKSPACE` file themselves.

I think the use of "root" in the page you linked is a bit confusing. That term has another meaning to the internals of Bazel, which is different from how it's used in that page. Most of the Bazel documentation just refers to the folder itself as "workspace" or "repository" without a separate term.

Comment: So the two terms really are synonyms.  But repository seems to be mostly used to refer to external workspaces, is that correct?

Comment: A folder being used as an external repository is not a workspace, even though it has a `WORKSPACE` file. If you run `bazel` from that folder, then it is the workspace for that bazel invocation, which will have a separate bazel server process from any other workspace.

Comment: I find that distinction a little unsatisfactory, but if that is the accepted convention then so be it.  I think the 'Getting Started' pages need to be updated to be clearer about this.  In effect, don't say "A workspace".  Instead it is "The workspace" (there can be only one).  All others are repositories until you start actually working in them.  Then your original workspace becomes a repository.